# MySQL NOT EXITS condition not working

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am trying to execute a mysql query but getting error which I can't understand. The query I am using is

```
INSERT INTO summary (oid,tab,cost) VALUES('1','7','40') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM summary WHERE cusid ='1')
```

I am using this tutorial as my reference, http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/exists.php

This is the structure of the summary table

[image: summary table structure]

This is the error message

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use new 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM summary WHERE cusid = 1)' at line 1

Comment: "but getting error which I can't understand" --- and you're not providing the error message so that it was funnier for us to guess it?

Comment: This question appears to be off topic because the problem is a simple typographical error.

Comment: You can't use `WHERE` with `INSERT`

Comment: Yup, there's no `WHERE` conditions to add in an `INSERT` statement ~ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that screenshotting your error message was a better idea than simply pasting the text into your question?

Comment: Probaly coz I wanted to show the query along with the error message and point out the the typo was while posting the question and not the actual cause? @Phil

Comment: While people love to downvote just to show they are way so much more cooler, the issue started coz the reference I was using shows `INSERT` being used with `WHERE`Completely my fault though I was trying to learn something downvote me folks !!!

Comment: @RickRoy The question is off topic anyway. You'll get the rep back because the question will soon be deleted.

Comment: @RickRoy Pro tip. When you get an SQL syntax error, the problem almost always starts at the character of the query quoted in the error.

Answer (score 0):

It is not `exits`. Change it to `exists`.

```
INSERT INTO summary (oid,tab,cost) VALUES('1','7','40') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM summary WHERE cusid ='1')
                                                                     ^
```

Also you can't use `NOT EXISTS` with your above query, you can with a subquery.

Comment: Sidenote: Are your integers stored as varchar in the database? because if not, `VALUES('1','7','40')` is wrong, as it's interpreting those as strings. Where it should be `VALUES(1,7,40)` most likely.

Comment: Still not working, gives the same error. No actually they were php variables

Comment: This is probably better as a comment as you still can't use a `WHERE` clause with an `INSERT` statement

Comment: You can't have a `WHERE` clause in an `INSERT` statement. If you want a conditional insert, use PHP.

Comment: I see I thought I was being clever trying to reduce php code :D

Comment: @Phil @worldofjr but the tutorial shows `INSERT` being used with `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @RickRoy There is no advantage of reducing PHP code in such circumstances. You're talking about less than 1ms extra run time.

Comment: @RickRoy The `WHERE` clause in that example is on the sub-query

Comment: @Phil thanks for all the help, but I am new to this and don't understand why this is not a subquery? and the one in example is could you please point me to a good tutorial or docs?

Comment: @RickRoy The tutorial you are following is fine. It's you that needs to follow it properly, and stop trying to "be clever" with your queries.